# Error about variable class in PanelMatch function in R

Tags: r, matching, panel-data

I cannot reproduce data for privacy reason. I am just curious if anyone has encountered the same problem since it might be internal error in **PanelMatch** package itself.

I have time.id, unit.id and treatment all integers; all the covariates and outcome variable are of numeric class. Still, when I run PanelMatch function I get this error:

> Warning: non-numeric data exists. Only numeric (including binary) data can be used for refinement and calculationsError in perform_refinement(lag = lag, time.id = time.id, unit.id = unit.id,  :
> no viable treated units for att specification

I know you can't reproduce the error, I'm just curious if anyone has encountered the same error while the variables are as they should be and what might be the reason for the error? Even though the treatmetn and control groups are unbalanced, in absolute terms, there are more than enough observations in both groups.

I have converted all the variables into integer and numeric variables, but the problem persists.

Comment: What version of `PanelMatch` are you using? There used to been an issue if the "unit.id" was non-contiguous/non-sequential e.g. 195843267. I was under the impression this bug was fixed in the most recent version. You could try making a sequential variable that runs from 1:n and use that instead to see if that fixes it. And although your data are confidential, it is possible to make a sample dataset that serves to replicate your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's 2.0 version of the package. And yes I have converted ID to sequential integers but still doesn't work.

Comment: The problem seems to be the unit.id variable. It was an integer variable but there were skips between the values (1, 3, 5, 8...). It had to be consecutive integers without omitting values (1,2,3,4,5...). 
In the end, I used match() function from dplyr to create a new unit.id variable with consecutive integers. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: SO encourages users to [answer their own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if they solve their problem. It would benefit others who may encounter your issue in the future if you did. Either way, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the unit.id variable. It was an integer variable but there were skips between the values (1, 3, 5, 8...). It had to be consecutive integers without omitting values (1,2,3,4,5...). In the end, I used match() function from dplyr to create a new unit.id variable with consecutive integers. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I would be super nice, if you would add pseude code for the match() function from dplyr to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the package now required the whole data to only include non-numeric data, which is insane. I keep only the data used for matching, then it works.